# Передача несколько значений одним вызовом

Tags: c++, linux

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что приходится вызывать функцию несколько раз с разными значениями для поиска. Как можно реализовать передачу значений одним вызовом?

```
void searching(string search)
{
// Функция
}

int main()
{
string word = " "; // значение
searching(word); // вызов функции
string word_2 = " ";
searching(word_2);
string word_3= " ";
searching(word_3);
...
}
```

Comment: Ничего не понял. Что эта функция будет делать с несколькими значениями, если она работает только с одним?

Comment: Может вы хотите передавать `vector<string>` (по сути массив строк)?

Comment: @AnT, Значение - ключ для поиска лексемы в файле. И вот этот ключ, не один, а несколько. И я хочу сделать это одним вызовом.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, да, всё верно. У меня есть один вариант, но он мне не подходит. `const vector<string> words = { "Value", "HelloWorld", "Test" , "agsaga" };` , а в функции это передается  с помощью цикла: `for (const string& search : searchs)`

Comment: Что значит "одним вызовом"? Что будет происходить внутри вашей функции, когда она получит много ключей? Зачем вы хотите это сделать "одним вызовом"? Почему вам "не подходит" вариант с `vector<string>`? Вам нужно осмысленно сформулировать задачу. Пока что вы лишь предоставили туманные стенания в стиле "вроде хочу так, но это вроде не подходит". Откуда же нам знать, что вам "подходит"?

Comment: AnT, суть задачи в том, что мне необходимо искать ключ в файле, и в случаи его наличия, надо вывести данные которые разделены от ключа разделителем  "=". Хочу сделать одним вызовом, так как это будет более правильно. Допустим, раньше у меня в функции открывался файл, а если его вызывать 4 раза, то это 4 раза открывается файл.. А это уже лишняя нагрузка.

Comment: Остается вопрос *"Почему вам "не подходит" вариант с vector<string>?"*

Comment: Вопрос, значит, не имеет ни какого отношения к "одним вызовом", а имеет отношение к тому, чтобы много раз не открывать и не закрывать файл. Но почему тогда вы пометили как "принятый" ответ, который вообще никак не решает проблемы открытия/закрытия файла??? И почему тогда `vector<string>` "не подходит"???

Comment: Перепишите саму функцию. Без этого ваши мечты выглядят как мечты ехать в одном поезде в четырех разных направлениях одновременно... Переписав, можете даже поиск делать не каждый раз по одному слову, а сразу всех слов чем-то типа алгоритма Ахо-Корасик. Замена же контейнера `vector` контейнером `initialize_list` абсолютно ничего не меняет...

Comment: Проблему решил.  А поставил галочку, потому что, тот вариант, который  предложили, тоже актуален.

Comment: Я решил проблему с помощью структуры. И вопрос был правильно задан,человек хотел узнать более подробно для чего мне это необходимо, я ему и ответил.

Comment: Но, благодарю вас за советы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вызовите её в цикле:

```
for (auto word : {"some", "other", "more"}) {
  searching(word);
}
```

Comment: И это принятый ответ.. похоже ОП вообще не знал чего он хочет.. или что он прочел )

Comment: @Swift, я выше написал причину, почему я принял этот вариант.